# Removing duplicate characters from a file - Python

Tags: python

I have a file as below,

```
this is Rdaaaa
thissss Is Sethaaa
hiii
```

I want to remove all the duplicate characters from this file..
I tried two code..
This completely removes duplicate chars but does not seem to be efficient code.

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f1:
with open("test1.txt", "w") as f2:
    #content = f1.readlines()
    char_set = set()
    while True:
        char = f1.read(1)
        if char not in char_set:
            char_set.add(char)
            f2.write(char)
        if not char:
            break
    print(char_set)
```

I also tried using regex following a stackoverflow post

```
import re
with open("test.txt", "r") as f1:
    with open("test1.txt", "w") as f2:
        content = f1.read()
        f2.write(re.sub(r'([a-z])\1+',r'\1',content))
```

But this  removes **thiish** to **thish** and **not** **thiish** to **this**

Any suggestions on the code with improved efficiency?

Answer (score 2):

For "medium" sized files that can fit into memory, this approach is a bit faster and fewer lines. You can load the whole file into memory, and then create a dictionary from it, where the dictionary's keys are the individual characters in the file. This keeps the output chars in the same order as when they were first seen (property of dict).

This ran in about 100ms for a 2 MB file with 11501 distinct characters. Your use case may make another approach better.

```py
# replace in_file and out_file with actual paths or file names
with open(in_file, "r") as f1, open(out_file, "w") as f2:
    txt = f1.read()
    ordered_set = ''.join(dict.fromkeys(txt).keys())
    f2.write(ordered_set)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big file, and you don't want to load it in the memory, you can read it line by line instead of character by character, which is much better and faster:

```py
file_input = open("old_file.txt", "r")
file_output = open("new_file.txt", "w")
memory = set()
while True:
    line = file_input.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    new_line = ""
    for char in line:
        if char == " ":
            new_line += char
            continue
        if char not in memory:
            memory.add(char)
            new_line += char
    file_output.writelines(new_line)
```

But if the file is small, you can read it once, and apply the same logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re

# read the file
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    # remove duplicate characters
    data = re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', data)
    # write the file
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

The output is:

```
this is Rda

this Is Setha

hi
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to delete letters that appear repeatedly in succession. Try using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> s = '''this is Rdaaaa
... thissss Is Sethaaa
... hiii'''
>>> print(''.join(map(itemgetter(0), groupby(s))))
this is Rda
this Is Setha
hi
```